# How to tighten the AMCL particle swarm envelope?

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking to tighten the envelope for the ensemble of points placed by AMCL, the topic is /particlecloud. I'm finding that I don't need to worry about the 'kidnapped robot problem', where the robot could suddenly be taken to any point on my map and the envelope stretches and randomly places estimates all over the map.

I'm driving my robot around by either teleop or 2D Nav Goal in rviz and the distribution of points shouldn't be moving further than something like a 2x2 m^2 radius.

Does anyone know the input parameter to amcl that can reduce the covariance? of particle swarm?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256440/how-to-tighten-the-amcl-particle-swarm-envelope-?/) by [j_salfity](https://answers.ros.org/users/27623/j_salfity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "Odometry model parameters" section on the [AMCL wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) describes the parameters that control the noise introduced into the particles during the odometry propagation step of the particle filter; it sounds like reducing the alpha parameters will probably do what you're asking.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0